# SQLite last 24h query with 2 rows date and time

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I want to query last 24h in my database SQLite. I have 2 rows time example (18:04:56) and date (2020-12-06 ). When I use this query

```
SELECT name,cdate,ctime, * FROM {table} WHERE  cdate  >= datetime('now','-1 day') ORDER BY id DESC
```

I got only last queries in the same day. (LAST QUERY 00:00:46)
How deal with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a datetime value from `cdate` and `ctime` to compare with `DATETIME('now','-1 day')`:

```
SELECT name, cdate, ctime  
FROM {table} 
WHERE  (cdate || ' ' || ctime) >= DATETIME('now','-1 day') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Your query getting  2020-12-05 00:00:58.
I want to getting currenly time -24h example now is 06.12.2020 18:18 and I want get 05.12.2020 18:18.

Comment: @Rysiusek I see what you mean. Check my edited answer.